# How to add a code without going to the next line (CF -> ConfigRule Resource)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to make my CF (generates a ConfigRule with Lambda Function inside) template look good. But if I do it doesn't work. So what I need to do is to go the the next line without

```
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
Properties:
  Description: Rule to evaluate tags in AWS Config
  Handler: index.lambda_handler
  Code:
    ZipFile: |
      import json
      import boto3
      import os

      # Specify desired resource types to validate         
      APPLICABLE_RESOURCES = ["AWS::EC2::Volume","AWS::EC2::Instance","AWS::Redshift::Cluster","AWS::Redshift::ClusterSnapshot","AWS::RDS::DBInstance","AWS::RDS::DBSnapshot","AWS::RDS::DBCluster","AWS::S3::Bucket*","AWS::CloudTrail::Trail","AWS::CodeBuild::Project*","AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline*","AWS::Lambda::Function","AWS::CloudFormation::Stack*","AWS::DynamoDB::Table"]
```

result: https://postimg.cc/2V32xHkz
objective: https://postimg.cc/4n21nzzj
Any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: placing the "[" on the next line ruins the code (the bracket turns white instead of brown.

Comment: But I can do it manually via LambdaFunction UI, hence the "objective" image url